# How to create different class objects in class constructor and overloading operators (C++)

Tags: c++, class

I need yours help. I'm quite newbie in C++ (still learning) and I struggling with class constructor which include object from different class. The task is to create Rectangle class which will be described by objects (Point class) , each corner is a object with x,y coordinates. Additionally I need overload operators << and >> in the way that by ">>" user input coordinates of each point during Rectangle object creation by constructor. 
When I using code as below I have error incomplete type is not allowed" on fields from p1 to p4.

List item

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point;
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(int p1x = 0, int p1y = 0, int p2x = 0, int p2y = 0, int p3x = 0, int p3y = 0, int p4x = 0, int p4y = 0) : p1(p1x, p1y), p2(p2x, p2y), p3(p3x, p3y), p4(p4x, p4y) 
    {

    };

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const Rectangle &rect);

private:
    Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    void change_cordinates(Rectangle &);
    int height, width;
};"
```

From the other hand, when i use #include "Point.h" directive I have problem with overloading << and >> with error "function Rectangle is not a type name"

I don't know if it's clear, but I hope I described my problem peaty clear (if not correct me please or ask)

Comment: You should probably include `point.h` and ask why the stream operators do not work.

Comment: You can't have members of incomplete type. `Point` is incomplete at the point where you declare your members. You've only declared it with `class Point;` but you haven't defined it.

Comment: not including something that is broken doenst fix it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: you'll have to ensure types are 'complete' when they are used.

In your example they are used by adding them as member variables.
You *could* work around this issue by holding pointers to them (instead of members) - but that is most likely a bad idea, as you then have to care about memory allocation/de-allocation.

Probably the best solution: include "Point.h" and fix your >> and << operators.